# Google Sign In idToken not including serverClientID after refreshing

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-signin

Using the Google Sign-In iOS SDK (v4.1.0), and following the guides to [add sign-in to my iOS app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift) and also having our backend engineer follow the [server auth guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth) we are successfully able to sign in via Google in our iOS app. But after an hour passes and after the `idToken` expires and the Sign-In SDK handles refreshing it, the `idToken` no longer has the `aud` property set to the `serverClientID` I set it to in `didFinishLaunching` and now instead set `aud` as the `clientID`.

My code is as follows in `didFinishLaunching`:

```
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = clientID
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().serverClientID = serverClientID
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = scopes
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
```

After the SDK has refreshed the token and inspecting the JWT google gives us with [Auth0's JWT checker](https://jwt.io), the JWT no longer has the `aud` property set to the previous `serverClientID`, and instead has it set to the `clientID`.

Has anyone else experienced this and found a solution?